# Is there a default Rake Task for Yard

Tags: ruby, rake, yard

Currently I have Yard as a separate shell file and call it in Circle CI config.yml file for my ruby project. Was wondering if there is a default rake task for Yard that I can use and then enable the rake task in config.yml

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Yard provides a Rake task, it is mentioned in the [README](https://github.com/lsegal/yard) in 'Usage' section and [documented](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/yard/YARD/Rake/YardocTask). Minimal working setup to put in Rakefile:

```
require "yard"

YARD::Rake::YardocTask.new do |t|
  t.files = ['lib/**/*.rb']
end
```

Running `rake yard` in shell will run the task and generate documentation in `doc` directory.